# Bitbucket Pipelines case-sensitive filesystem

Tags: gulp, bitbucket-pipelines

Tech: gulp, polymer-build, bitbucket pipelines

I have a build step as part of a project which copies a bunch of bower_components files into the /dist folder. When run locally this works fine. However when running the same script on Bitbucket, it fails when reaching the module Chart.js

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/bower_components/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'
```

I believe the module cannot be found because of the capital 'C'. Since pipelines runs docker, is it possible to ensure that the filesystem is case-insensitive?

The build task is run with gulp and polymer-build, but I cannot find anything around case-insensitive copying or piping, and since the task runs fine on a mac. I believe it is an issue with the environment. Has anyone come across similar issues with the filesystem?